# Improvement in AI of Ubuntu game

Tags: games, source-code

I have developed an AI for an Ubuntu game. My AI beats the existing Ubuntu AI. So I want to contribute to the improvement of AI of that game.

Where should I send my source code, where do I communicate regarding the same?

Answer (score 1):

IMO for a major change like this, you should contact the upstream developers. And where and how you can do that varies from project to project. Standard means of communication on Ubuntu development (mailing lists, Launchpad, etc.) will get you in touch with the people who package software for Ubuntu, but usually won't connect you with the original developers, especially for third-party software like games.

Tracking down the original upstream might a bit of work. Look for the homepage in `http://packages.ubuntu.com/<release>/<package>` (you can also run `apt-cache show <package>`). Then hunt for instructions on the homepage.

With `0ad`, for example, http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/0ad says the homepage is http://play0ad.com/, and that site will eventually lead you to http://trac.wildfiregames.com/wiki/GettingStartedProgrammers which has instructions for contributing to the project.

If the homepage doesn't help you, then you can post a question on the Launchpad page for that package (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/0ad/+bugs for 0ad) (or on the maililing list, maybe [`ubuntu-devel-discuss`](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/Ubuntu-devel-discuss)), and the maintainers should be able to provide you information about upstream.